# Right now i and j will both be on the different line when i execute it. How can I get the answers of i and j on the same line?

Tags: c#

```
namespace Nested_While_Loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (i < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i value: {0}", i);
                i++;
                int j = 1;
                while (j < 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("j value: {0}", j);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter Key to Exit..");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

This is a simpleNested while loop.
**How can I write Console.WriteLine(" i :{0},j : {0}", i, j);**
I am getting many errors.

Comment: The code you have provided, while valid _C#_, would result in a compiler error for _C_. Are you sure you intended to include that tag? I recommend editing your question to remove it.

Comment: Just use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Have you tried with Console.WriteLine(" i :{0}, j : {1}", i, j);

Comment: "I am getting many errors." - tip: always be very explicit about *what errors you are seeing*, so that people can understand what you mean by that

Comment: It is giving me the answer Like this: i value: 1j value: 1i value: 2j value: 1i value: 3j value: 1Press Enter Key to Exit..  and i have to get the answer like this : Console.WriteLine("i value: {0}, j value: {1}", i, j);

Answer (score 3):

The `{0}` (etc) in a format string indicates the zero-based index of the value argument to add, so you *could* use:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("i value: {0}, j value: {1}", i, j);
```

However, you may find it clearer to use string interpolation:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"i value: {i}, j value: {j}");
```